# Why is a particular neutrino PMNS matrix called tribimaximal mixing?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

Why is it that the neutrino mixing matrix of the form $$U_{TBM}=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2/3} & \sqrt{1/3} & 0\\-\sqrt{1/6} & \sqrt{1/3} & -\sqrt{1/2}\\-\sqrt{1/6} & \sqrt{1/3} & \sqrt{1/2}\end{pmatrix}$$ is called a **[tribimaximal mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribimaximal_mixing)** pattern? I've often seen the terms trimaximal, bimaximal, tribimaximal etc being used without justifying the name.

Is there a specific reason why such mixing pattern was popular in the early literature of neutrino physics? I mean, were these patterns theoretically dictated by one or more flavour symmetries?

Comment: If you're just asking for the *origin* of a terminology as opposed to a question about the actual physics, consider asking at [hsm.SE] next time. A priori there's no guarantee that any particular terminology actually has something to do with the physics described (exihibit A: [Penguin diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penguin_diagram))

Comment: There is rarely a specific reason people conjecture  pretty  mixing matrices for generations, beyond the hope that they might hit it right before experiment comes in to frustrate them. It happened with the Fritzsch, Stech, etc, matrices in the quark sector, until their unworkability was confirmed; and it has happened again with the neutrino sector. There is a metaphysical hope that somehow, another Balmer formula will be discovered by blind guessing, and thus lead to the right theories that produce such. All models leading to such formulas were constructed *after* the matrices, not *before*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is given by [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribimaximal_mixing). Look at the columns of the mixing matrix - they dictate the composition of the neutrino mass eigenstates. The sums of the squares of the coefficients in every row and column must equal one to presevere unitarity.

The second mass eigenstate is a maximal, equal mixture of all 3 flavor eigenstates (trimaximal) - we see $1/\sqrt3$ appear 3 times. The third is a maximal, equal mixture of 2 flavors (bimaximal). The first column is then dictated by unitarity. There is still a choice of phase, in this case chosen to be zero.

Comment: So in a sense tribimaximal is both trimaximal as well as bimaximal. Am I right? Also I've edited the body and title of the question. Can you throw some light on the additional queries? @innisfree

Answer (score 0):

The TBM pattern was popular in the literature when $\theta_{13}$ was not so accurately measured and believed to be zero, and $\theta_{23}=\pi/4$ i.e., maximal atmospheric mixing. Though the atmospheric mixing can still be maximal, a nonzero value of $\theta_{13}$ (in experiments such as RENO and Daya Bay) now rules out the TBM mixing pattern. It was also popular in the literature because some models some discrete symmetries directly give this mixing pattern.